# Integer allocation problem alternative to MI-SOCP?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, second-order-cone-programming

Can the following problem be solved without needing to use a MI-SOCP solver? I think I can code it as just a simple parallel branch-and-bound search but I'm not sure if the performance will be close to MI-SOCP for low dimensions or scale well.

A number of integer share quantities $q_i$ bought at a price $p_i$ need to be integer allocated $a_{ij}$ to a number of accounts with a given total quantity $n_j = \sum_i a_{ij}$ such that the accounts get the most similar possible average prices $\frac {\sum_i a_{ij} p_i}{n_j}$.

Comment: You want $q_i=\sum_j a_{ij}$?  How do you measure "most similar" here?

Comment: Yes $q_i = \sum_j a_{ij}$. Minimise sum of square difference to global average would be SOCP problem I think but sum of absolute differences would be another possible measure.

Comment: Or maybe minimise max absolute difference to global average price ($\frac {\sum_i q_i p_i} {\sum_i q_i}$). Btw $\sum_i q_i = \sum_j n_j$ and the $n_j$ are calculated based on account weighting at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\bar{p} = \frac{\sum_i p_i}{\sum_j n_j}$ be the global average price.  Introduce nonnegative surplus $s_j$ and slack $t_j$ variables.  Here are two linear approaches.

- Minimize the sum of absolute differences to $\bar{p}$: minimize $\sum_j (s_j + t_j)$ subject to
  \begin{align}
  \sum_j a_{ij} &= q_i &\text{for all $i$} \\
  \sum_i a_{ij} &= n_j &\text{for all $j$} \\
  \frac{\sum_i p_i a_{ij}}{n_j} - s_j + t_j &= \bar{p} &\text{for all $j$}
  \end{align}
- Minimize the maximum absolute difference to $\bar{p}$: minimize $z$ subject to
  \begin{align}
  \sum_j a_{ij} &= q_i &\text{for all $i$} \\
  \sum_i a_{ij} &= n_j &\text{for all $j$} \\
  \frac{\sum_i p_i a_{ij}}{n_j} - s_j + t_j &= \bar{p} &\text{for all $j$} \\
  s_j + t_j &\le z &\text{for all $j$}
  \end{align}

Comment: These would need branch and bound MIP solvers? Any idea of the performance difference between these and the MI-SOCP? I was hoping for a branch and bound algorithm that doesn't need a solver.

Comment: Yes, a MILP solver would be the simplest choice, rather than writing an explicit branch-and-bound algorithm from scratch.  I would expect either MILP problem to solve faster than the corresponding MISOCP problem, but it is worth trying all three.

Comment: Thanks for your help.